# Slack app crashes Ubuntu desktop

Tags: ubuntu, slack

I am using the Slack app on Ubuntu 22.04. I find that if I right click and paste the app stops running immediately. Otherwise, at random times I lose all USB input and the screen goes black for about ten seconds. The screen recovers but the USB will not until I reboot my computer.

This only ever occurs when using the Slack app. Can anyone shed any light on this issue?

I'm running linux kernel  5.19.0-32-generic. I don't want to upgrade from LTS versions.

Comment: Facing a similar issue. Sometimes when I open the Slack app, the screen goes black for a second but then comes back and i cant use it anymore. The whole pc freezes. Did you fix it?

Comment: Not yet. I also lose mouse and I suspect all USB. Unplugging and replugging does not help. A hard reboot fixes it for a while. The issue is random and only occurs occasionally. I suspect a bug in the Slack app for linux. It appears to happen after an hour or two using a browser and then occurs as soon as I click into the Slack app..

Comment: I've been having this same issue for the last week or two. I tried installing the `insider/edge` version and I still experience this.

Comment: Similar (same) question pointing at a fix by upgrading the Linux kernel.
https://superuser.com/questions/1770961/slack-randomly-completely-makes-computer-freeze-crash

Comment: Guys, I got it fixed without upgrading the kernel. Apparently the issue is with Slack that has been installed with Snap. Uninstall that and install it from official website or some other package manager.

Comment: Yes, uninstalling snap version and installing version from slack site solved it for me too. Thanks @s.khan! Now also drop-down menus are working well and they didn't work before.

Comment: @MilanG can you screenshare in a huddle? I never could since I upgraded to 22.04.

Comment: It worked for me removing Slack for me $ sudo snap remove slack and then installing the .deb package downloaded from the website. It was the same version but it is working now.