# Slack randomly completely makes computer freeze / crash

Tags: slack, ubuntu-22.04

I don't know if it's the right place to ask this, don't hesitate to tell me if this isn't the case

Starting from today, Slack randomly crashes and freezes my computer, forcing me to force reboot. I managed to extract this log from /var/log/syslog :

```
Feb 27 08:56:53 pc-de-jeremy kernel: [  794.539163] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: [mmhub0] no-retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:40 vmid:1 pasid:32777, for process slack pid 6335 thread slack:cs0 pid 6376)
Feb 27 08:56:53 pc-de-jeremy kernel: [  794.539176] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800102c30000 from IH client 0x12 (VMC)
Feb 27 08:56:53 pc-de-jeremy kernel: [  794.539181] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00140050
Feb 27 08:56:53 pc-de-jeremy kernel: [  794.539182] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu:     Faulty UTCL2 client ID: MP1 (0x0)
Feb 27 08:56:53 pc-de-jeremy kernel: [  794.539184] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu:     MORE_FAULTS: 0x0
Feb 27 08:56:53 pc-de-jeremy kernel: [  794.539185] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu:     WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
Feb 27 08:56:53 pc-de-jeremy kernel: [  794.539186] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu:     PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x5
Feb 27 08:56:53 pc-de-jeremy kernel: [  794.539187] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu:     MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
Feb 27 08:56:53 pc-de-jeremy kernel: [  794.539188] amdgpu 0000:05:00.0: amdgpu:     RW: 0x1
```

Whenever a crash happens and I don't reboot immediately, I get a lot of this error.

I found some issues about some error looking a lot like mine, like this one : https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/2113, but I didn't find a solution yet.

Last time I used Slack was about 2 weeks ago and it worked fine

I tried to update every upgradable package (including amd-related drivers), no luck

Thanks for your time and help !

Comment: I seem to have same issue, started happening few days ago .. will write email to feedback@slack.com

Comment: Same here, if you fix it please write a response to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I still don't know what the issue was, but it was fixed in the version 6.1 of the Linux Kernel. I updated it and the error hasn't happened since. Unfortunately it seems that Ubuntu does not let you update the Kernel without updating the OS itself. You can upgrade from mainline with the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-6.1.0-1006-oem \
    linux-image-6.1.0-1006-oem \
    linux-modules-6.1.0-1006-oem \
    linux-tools-6.1.0-1006-oem
```

I think the mainline channel isn't as well tested as the official channels, so use at your own risk. Though, on my end, it fixed the issue and did not cause any others.

Comment: Yep, I decided to go with kernel before 5.19 that introduced this bug, so I select it in grub menu on startup, advanced options. I'll wait for official 6.1 update as I don't like to run these kind of commands on my work laptop :)

Comment: Thanks man, so annoying bug